# Running K6 with docker-compose creating a new container instead start an old one

Tags: docker-compose, k6

I using K6 + InfluxDB + Grafana with docker-compose, but i got a problem.

After create and start new containers using `docker-compose up -d grafana influxdb` when i run k6 using `docker-compose run k6 run` a new container is created instead start an old one.

[image]

I followed step by step of [this](https://community.k6.io/t/preload-grafana-dashbaord-with-docker-compose-setup/874) tutorial.

Have you guys any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is put --rm in the command: `docker-compose run --rm k6 run`.
Find solution [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/).